# Laravel validation - field A required when one of two conditions is acheived: field B filled or filed C has a specific value

Tags: validation, controller, laravel-8, required, unless

Laravel validation - field A required unless when one of two conditions is acheived: field B filled or filed C has a specific value

Hi
I have control panel for news website
with  three filed
source
writer_id
place_id

I need "source" to be required except two situtions:
1/ "place_id" = 4
2/ "writer_id" is filled
In these situtions I havenot to insert any value in "source"

I tried the next order but fiald:
request()->validate([
'source' =>'required_unless:place_id,4 ||  required_without:writer_id', ]);

But if insert one of these condition, it succeed.

How I make the two conditions work together?

[failed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pViAu.png)

I need "source" to be required except two situtions:
1/ "place_id" = 4
2/ "writer_id" is filled
In these situtions I havenot to insert any value in "source"

'source' =>'required_unless:place_id,4 ||  required_without:writer_id', ]); >> Failed